# How to stop the incompleted animation while mouse out and then mouse in again in .hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am trying to use .hover() to hide and show the options while user mouse in the image.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').hover(
    function(){
        $('.caption').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1200);
    },
    function(){
        $('.caption').hide(1200)});});
```

Right now the animation works, but if I mouse enter and mouse out multiple times quickly, the speed of the repetition of the tag cannot catch up with the mouse. And I want while I hover again, the incomplete animation could pause what its doing and execute the present calling.

I tried to add a `.stop()` but then the function could not repeat while I mouse in again anymore

Does anyone know how to do it, thanks.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/aznEa/2/

Comment: See here http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use stop(true,true) in Jquery.We can use create a nice slide effect without the
>   common problem of multiple queued animations by adding .stop(true,
>   true) to the chain:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test').hover(
        function(){
            $('.caption').stop(true,true).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1200);
        },
        function(){
            $('.caption').stop(true,true).hide(100)});
});
```

Comment: oh thanks so much, I never know the .stop() could be add there.

Comment: but it seems it has bugs, while I tried mouse in and mouse out fast several times, the tag has been threw out of the div. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: you use stop() or stop(true,true);

Comment: I use stop(true, true) in the first, stop(true) in the second, and the same situation while I use stop(true) in both places, you could try it

Comment: But i am work in jsfiddle its shows right. there is no issues.

Comment: Ok I thought it was JSFiddle problem

Comment: stop(true,false). Now check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47629/discussion-between-tamizh-and-james-chen)

Answer (score 0):

Use $('.caption').clearQueue() on mouse out.

This will clear the current animation under process

Refer :http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').hover(
    function(){
        $('.caption').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1200);
    });

$('#test').mouseout(function(){
    $('.caption').stop().show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1200);
        $('.caption').hide(100);
});
});
```

see js fiddle at  http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/aznEa/2/